# How can I make tags-search able to find created timestamps containing both date and time?

Tags: org-mode

I have made a tags search to filter out todo's created today:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands'(
    ("d" "todo's made today" tags "TODO=\"TODO\"+Created=\"<today>\"" (
    (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(scheduled-up))
    (org-agenda-overriding-header "TODO's created today")
    ))
))
```

My todo's contains a created timestamp as a property:

```
:PROPERTY:
:Created: [2015-07-30 on 21:33]
:END:
```

hence, the timestamp contains both date and time.

However, my tags search do not find tasks created today unless I change the todo's timestamp format to contain date only, like in [2015-07-30 on].

How can I change the tags search format to find today's timestamps when these contain both data end time?

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions : )

Comment: I do not believe that the stock-version of `org-mode` in the most recent public release of Emacs contains sufficient text-properties (and related functions to determine values) to organize by date the data returned during `org-tags-view`.  I have not looked at more recent `org-mode` versions to see what improvements have been made, but I received an email from someone on the mailing list that *some* functions would be receiving upgrades to support sorting by `org-entries-lessp`.  I don't use `org-agenda-custom-commands`, so I'll let another forum participant tackle that aspect of the question.

Comment: I see that the original poster is not using a time-stamp format that matches `org-time-stamp-formats` -- i.e., `%Y-%m-%d %a` or `%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M`.  Choosing a different format with extra words like **`on`**, and omitting the abbreviated day of the week, may lead to incompatibility problems with certain functions later on down the road.  If the original poster is using a different language where **`on`** is a day of the week, then please excuse me.

Comment: Is there a reason the timestamp is not in the standard format (`[2015-07-30  21:33]`)?

Comment: eirikstokes: Is the standard format like this: `[2015-07-30 21:33]`, not containing the weekday? I thought the timestamp format always contained the weekday?(`http://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps`). Since I started using emacs some weeks ago the timestamps have shown the weekday.But for some unknown reasons, some days ago the language of the weekday changed from english to norwegian, like `[2015-07-29 Wed 09:30]` to `[2015-07-29 on 09:30]`, where "on" stands for "onsdag".

Comment: I am not aware of which init-file changes I have made that have changed the weekday format from english to norwegian.

Comment: The weekday is optional. When org inserts one it always adds the weekday, but you can put them in without.

Comment: The variables controlling the day names seem to be: `calendar-day-abbrev-array`, `calendar-day-name-array`, `parse-time-weekdays`. Have these changed?

Comment: Thanks! I will check whether any of these variables has changed :)

Comment: The two first variables you mention are both in englsh version, the third is not set. How can my days show up in norwegian abbreviations ? strange..