# How can I make column view show a column with the timestamp for when a task was DONE?

Tags: org-agenda

I am using the column view on my org agendas, and I want one of the columns to show the timestamp for when the task was finilize (set to "DONE" state). I tried the following column headings

`#+COLUMNS: %DONE`
`#+COLUMNS: %CLOSED`

but neither of them worked. I have not found any special properties for the DONE time (althought I thought CLOSED was exactly that), so I have tried the column heading `#+COLUMNS: %TIMESTAMP_IA`. However, this will show all type of inactive timestamps, not only timestamps for DONE. Another approach would be to include the timestamp for "DONE" as a property of the task, though I have no idea of how to do that.

So,
1) how can I include a timestamp for DONE as a column in column view?
2) how to make a timestamp for DONA a property of a task?

Thanks in advance for all helpfull suggestions :)

Comment: `CLOSED` is the property you want.  I have `(org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%25ITEM %TODO %CLOSED %TAGS")` in some agendas and it works.

Comment: hm..strange. It does not work. Retested it just now. My DONE timestams is set on the form `[2015-07-30 to 10:29]` with norwegian day format

Comment: That's probably the issue: org-mode is not parsing the timestamp correctly.  It's the same problem as [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14343/how-can-i-make-tags-search-able-to-find-created-timestamps-containing-both-date](your other question).  This may just be a bug in org-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to set the `org-log-done` variable to `time` and then use the CLOSED column in your agendas.

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Closing-items.html